# Find key by value in python3 json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing, file-io

I have a json object: users.json

```
{ 
  "1" :
       { "name" : "Jason" } , 
  "2" : 
       { "name" : "Alex" }
}
```

I have a python function which takes as input a name and should return the "id". For example if I pass 'Jason', it should return '1' and if I pass 'Alex' it should return '2'. I know this is a simple question but I am really stuck...(and a bit lazy to study python dictionnaries...) Here is what I have so far

```
def __init__(self):
    self.users_file = 'users.json'

def read_users_file(self):
    with open(self.users_file) as users_file:
        return json.load(users_file)

def get_user_id(self, name):  
    data = self.read_users_file()
    values = data.values()
    for val in data.values():
        if(name == val.get('name')):
            print('user found!')
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think your code is better than that in the answer you accepted. The only problem I see is the redundant `values = data.values()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = {
    "1":
    {"name": "Jason"},
    "2":
    {"name": "Alex"}
}


name = 'Jason'

for key in d:
    if (d[key]['name'] == name):
        print(key) ## output 1
```

or in more Pythonic way:

```
for key, value in data.items():
    if name == value['name']:
        print(key)
```